# Website Duplication issue

Tags: seo, web-hosting, website-design, webserver

We just launched our New site with lots of changes in design and content. After getting into my Cpanle i came to know that my website developing company have done this to my site.

The old site is running live on this IP (68.178.212.104)

while

the new one is on www.acethehimalaya.com

and it seems the old site is assigned to dedicated server

while

the new one is just using the domain name pointed to some other IP.

Both the site have similar content so is there any issues regarding the SEO ? It seems the files of my new site is somehere else. I m not able to contact my web developers so can i  get some suggestion. what i need to do exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything about this.

The primary identification of the site is the domain name, and that's an alias for the hosts IP address (among other things). When you change hosts, you change the IP the domain points to (if you're not transferring the domain).

So if the search engines don't get a link pointing to the old IP in it, there won't be any duplicate content.

Comment: Thanks a lot! is it good to use the same IP for the old domain ? or is it ok with the change of IP ?

Comment: To my knowledge It matters in a fraction for local country SEO, local results get a slight advantage than international results. And the location is defined by the IP address. If you move hosts, you change the IP the domain points to.

Comment: What if [`site:68.178.212.104`](https://www.google.com/#q=site:68.178.212.104) is showing results in the SERPs?

Comment: @w3d: It means that there's a link on the internet to that IP which google has indexed.

Comment: Doesn't it also mean that you **do** need to do something about this?

Comment: Easy, modify/delete/redirect the links in question. [link:68.178.212.104](https://www.google.hu/#q=link:68.178.212.104) can help you eliminate the links in question, but don't expect a quick update as google has to crawl the site or sites in question for these links to be removed.